# order of rows with drag and drop in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, grid

I am using the drag and drop function in a grid like this:

```
{
xtype: 'gridpanel',
id: 'editlinesGrid',
title: 'line',
forceFit: true,
store: 'gridEditlines',
region: 'center',
viewConfig: {
    plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop', {
        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop'
    })],
    listeners: {
        drop: {
            fn: me.onGriddragdroppluginDrop,
            scope: me
        }
    }
},
columns: [{
    xtype: 'rownumberer',
    dataIndex: 'stopOrder'
}, {
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'stopId',
    text: 'stopId',
    field: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        allowBlank: false,
        displayField: 'stopId',
        store: 'gridStops'
    }
},
```

When i drag the row to a higher or lower position i need to send the new position to the service. What i need to send is this:

```
{
"stopOrder": 1,  <-- here should be the new position in the grid
"stopDTO": {
"stopId" : 1
}
}
```

this is the eventbinding i use for the drag and drop

```
 onGriddragdroppluginDrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, options) {
    alert(data);
},
```

What do i need to do to send the data back to the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as question is not answered, and me also spend some time to 'find' it, this is link to main sencha doc [Reorder grid rows using DnD](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop)